# Is it allowed to generate temporary files?

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I have not yet submitted any Office add-in.

For the add-in I am developing, a JavaScript function will generate a temporary `.txt` file, which will be treated by another JavaScript function. Does anyone know if the server of Office Add-ins permits of generating temporary files like that?

Is there any example in https://github.com/OfficeDev that uses temporary file?

If it is not allowed, which would be the data type to represent large unstructured information (like text) to be passed among JavaScript functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all web-based Office add-ins use JavaScript, you have no interaction with the local PC nor the web server where the add-in's pages are hosted.  If you need to do file manipulation you could for example call REST endpoints (via Ajax from your JavaScript) on your web server which could use server-side code (such as the ASP.NET Web API, NodeJS, etc.) to do the file work and return results to your JS code.

Comment: So, does it mean: because all the JS codes are hosted on my server, I could do whatever I want on my server (eg, generating a temporary file)?

Comment: Microsoft only hosts the manifest file, whereas all the JS and HTML codes are hosted on my server, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. JS & HTML are hosted on your server and you can use server-side processing to store files. In addition you can also use client-side technologies like HTML5 [Window.sessionStorage and Window.localStorage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg142799(v=vs.85).aspx) for temporary storage locations.